# Can you optimize this SQL query for me?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm running this query in 2 mysql_query calls.  I would like to do the most performant thing and run it in one query.   Can anyone optimize this for me:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(eq("select * 
                        from player_data 
                       where uid = $uid")) == 0 )
      eq("update player_data 
             set uid = $uid, 
                `stat`= REPLACE(`stat`, '$temp_uid', '$uid') 
           where uid = $temp_uid");
```

Note: eq is just a wrapper function for mysql_query

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
eq("update player_data 
       set uid = $uid, 
           `stat`=REPLACE(`stat`, '$temp_uid', '$uid') 
     where uid=$temp_uid 
       and not exists (select * 
                         from player_data 
                        where uid = $uid)");
```

Comment: Here you can use `select *` inside exists-clause because its not going to generate any result set.

Comment: The SELECT on an EXISTS will never execute - EXISTS only returns true on the first match.  You could change it to `EXISTS(SELECT 1/0 ...)` and you won't receive a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows(eq("select 1 from player_data where uid=$uid")) == 0 )
      eq("update player_data set uid=$uid, `stat`=REPLACE(`stat`, '$temp_uid', '$uid') where uid=$temp_uid");
```

Avoid `select *` if you just want to get the count of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Will A's answer is very good, and if you do need to select a field specify it.  Selecting everything is terrible for performance.